# Docker Container Logs for short lived containers

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm stack and an application that run various docker containers to perform certain services. Sometimes those services take 10 minutes, some times, 3 seconds.

Looking for a solution to be able to read the docker logs from all of those services. For the containers that run longer, it can be easily achieved with `docker log xxx` but if the container starts up and dies shortly after, I can't do the same.

Appreciate any ideas on how I can log logs of all containers that start and stop. `docker events` don't get me any info.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a different [logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/#supported-logging-drivers), so that logs are persistently stored. The default, `json-file`, does not keep logs after containers are deleted. If you are using Docker CE, switch to `journald` and you can view Docker logs in the systemd journal (and syslog, if you have journal entries copied to syslog as most people do) as well as with `docker logs`. You have more logging options with Docker Enterprise, which are listed on Docker's web site, or you can configure systemd-journald to export logs to a wide variety of external destinations.

Comment: At least on my system (Ubuntu 18 server) the default logs are persisted after the container is stopped. Only after I remove the container I cannot access them anymore.

Comment: @JurajMartinka Short lived one time containers are usually started with the `--rm` option, which automatically deletes the container after it exits.

Comment: That's a good point but I appreciate you updated your answer to be more precise :).