# View logs from short lived containers in docker stack

Tags: docker, logging, debug

Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/1024362/docker-container-logs-for-short-lived-containers), but with the intricacies of the docker stack added.

While debugging short lived containers on vanilla docker is "easy", you just do `docker logs -f "failed_container_id"`, how can I do the same for containers started via docker stack?

I tried the following but none work:

```
docker logs -f stackname_containername

docker logs -f stackname_containerid

docker logs -f containername

docker logs -f containerid
```

All of these attempts result in

> Error response from daemon: No such container: XXXX

I also tried looking at the output of `docker stack services stackname` as suggested by my local friendly chatbot and using the service's id in the command `docker service logs stackname_servicename` but this just outputs nothing.

So how is it that I can see logs fine with "regular" docker containers but not with the ones started as part of a stack?